# Total number of iterations in $d$ nested for loops

Tags: combinatorics, matlab, programming

Assume that there are $d$ number of *for loops* in a computer program. Let it be for example Matlab. A pseudo code will look like this:

```
for i=1:N
   for j=i:N
      for k=j:N
         ..
         ..
      do something (costs one operation)
      end
    end
end
```

> **a.** How many operations are performed altogether in terms of $N$ and $d$. Is there any formula for this?
>
> **b.** Is there any way to write a computer program for example in Matlab, which will automatically create $d$ such *for loops* whenever the number $d$ is given?

**Added**: A combinatorics correspondance of the problem is the $d$-tuple combinations of numbers ranging from $1$ to $N$ without regarding the ordering. For example triple combinations of numbers from $1$ to $3$:

$(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3)...(3,3,3)$ here we do not have the terms $(1,2,1)$ and $(2,1,1)$ because they are the same with $(1,1,2)$. The same goes to for example $(1,3,1)$ and $(3,1,1)$ etc.

Comment: Negative voters, if this question is asked, please direct me to the source. I searched for a long time to find a similar question with no success. Probably I was not using the necessary keywords. This question corresponds to $d$-tuple combinations numbers from $1$ to $N$ without regarding the ordering. For example triple combinations and numbers from $1$ to $3$, then $(112)$ will appear only once because $(121)$ and $(211)$ are the same with $(112)$.

Comment: @Moo thanks for the comment. I can do it and get answers for some specific $N$ and $d$. There is no doubt for that. However, this problem is the same with a combinatorics problem as I tried to explain in my previous comment. Therefore this should already be known. There is a Matlab tag and therefore I thought maybe its okay to ask **b** here too. Btw, it doesnt matter if you downvoted because I have only $1$ points and happily enough Mathematics stack exhange doesnt allow negative points:)

Comment: @Moo you may ask why do I wann know this information a priori.. Because I would like to create a vector with zeros beforehand, so that my code will run without on the fly memory allocation, which will slow down everything..

Comment: I don't get why the question got so many downvotes? To me it looks fine...

Comment: Yes, although there is a programming element that probably belongs elsewhere, there is also a mathematical question here. New user upvoted to reward engagement.

Comment: @JuliusL33t thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were iterating through all choices of $d$ distinct values from a set of $N$, the total number of such choice is given by the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) 
$$\binom Nd= \frac{N!}{(N-d)!\cdot d!}$$

The total number of choices here is all choices of nondecreasing values; this can be transformed into the above case by adding $(0,1,2,...,d{-}1)$ to the values, meaning the result is 
$$\binom {N+d-1}d= \frac{(N+d-1)!}{(N-1)!\cdot d!}$$

You can iterate across these options without nested `for` loops by retaining an array of values and incrementing suitably, but that's not really a mathematics question.

Comment: no. let $N=3$ and $d=3$, or ever worse let $N=3$ and $d=4$.

Comment: @memeandme slight misread of the question, corrected

Comment: okay the last one seems working. how did you get it?

Comment: Putting it the other way round to my answer, imagine choosing all increasing value $d$-tuples from $N+d-1$ options, then reducing each tuple by $(0,1,....,d{-}1)$, giving non-decreasing $d$-tuples from $N$. There are other ways to get to the same formula also.

Comment: i cannot upvote as I am under 15 years old

Comment: and now I am 8 years old.. so pity you are ca. 31.000 years old. maybe you are drakula?